# What's wrong with that circuit? IR circuit with a relay and a regulator

Tags: sensor, relay, infrared

• I want to power up the **IR Circuit** and the pump with the same powering source, in order to do that I used a **5V Regulator**.

• The **OUT** of the IR circuit is 3.3V.

I have some problem here, when I connect the IR circuit's OUT to relay's coil pin, the I make the IR sensor detect some obstacle I hear some noise from the relay, and it cannot operate the pump.

What did I do wrong here?

**NOTE**

• I used HK4100F-DC3V-SHG Relay! [HK4100F-DC3V-SHG Datasheet](https://www.datasheetq.com/HK4100F-DC3V-SHG-doc-Unspecified)

• I made the IR Module myself, and I provided it's diagram.

[image: IR Module Diagram]

[image: Schematic diagram of my circuit]

Comment: we don't know anything about the IR module. We'll need a datasheet that says it can even drive a relay coil.

Comment: Also, no capacitors on the regulator. The relay is with 3V coil, 5V might be too much for it - if the IR module even can drive that...

Comment: the IR circuit's out is 3.3V, which is connected with relay's coil pin as in the diagram.

Comment: We need links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the IR module and the relay. You haven't provided enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Best guess : the relay needs more current than the IR module can supply. But without datasheets, that's only a guess.

Comment: @BrianDrummond 
That's my guess too, I provided the relay datasheet, and IR module diagram,

Comment: Yup - 45 ohm resistance, needs 75mA at 3.3V. That's more than an LM358 can provide.

Comment: @BrianDrummond
ohh , so what's your suggestion?

Comment: @BrianDrummond
This issue occurred when I tried to power the whole circuit from the same powering source, which means when I add the 5V regulator to the circuit, before that I connect the IR circuit with 5V adapter, and the relay with the pump connected with 12V one and everything was fine.

Comment: @BrianDrummond
but when I was powering up with two different sources, I was also hearing noise from the relay as if It struggle to operate the pump